# Python Script not attaching PDF attachments when the task scheduler is used to run the script

Tags: python, email, pdf

I am using the following program to send an email with pdf attachments. The program runs successfully and I get the email with the attachments, but when I use a task scheduler to run the program, I get the email with the body but no attachments. What could be the reason? I need this program to run and send out the email at 7 pm each day. Is there another way to get the program to run at a specific time without using the task scheduler?

Following is my program:

```
    import smtplib
    import os
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
    from email import encoders
    from os import path
    from glob import glob

    email_user = '#sender address#'
    email_send = '#reciever address#'
    subject = 'Subject'

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_user
    msg['To'] = email_send
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    body = "Hello:\nPlease find attached the reports"
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

    path = (r'''#path of the files to be attached''')
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(f)]
    filenames = filter(lambda f: f.endswith(('.pdf','.PDF')), files)
    for filename in filenames:
        attachment = open(filename, 'rb')
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename = 
           "+filename)

        msg.attach(part)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user,'#password#')


    server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
    server.quit()
```

Comment: Can the user that runs your task access the files in question? Is the path relative or absolute?

Comment: Yes the user can access the files and the path is absolute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir` strips the path information, so this script will only work when the working directory is the same as the one in "path". Your task scheduler is apparently not working there. So you need to provide the full path:

```
path = (r'''#path of the files to be attached''')
files = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]
files = filter(os.path.isfile, files)
```

I see you imported glob but you don't use it. That would be the best way to go, since it returns the full path AND it can do the extension filtering. You can make it case insensitive like this:

```
files = glob(os.path.join(path, '*.[pD][dD][fF]'))
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you. now the problem is that the attachment contains the entire path as the file name.

Comment: I figured it out. os.path.basename() does the job. Once again thank you

Comment: Any way to replace the windows task scheduler by using python script or anyother idea?

Comment: @Reems yes there are several modules like [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) but they all require a daemon (permanent background process). Using the OS's task scheduler is much better.